# Getting Crosswalk to work with Phonegap Build

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build, crosswalk

I have a native app that I'm using Phonegap Build to compile. I am trying to use the `Crosswalk Webview` plugin in my app.

According to the official [Phonegap blog](http://phonegap.com/blog/2015/05/26/npm-plugins-available/), all plugins are now hosted on NPM. According to this blog post, plugins tagged `ecosystem:cordova` should work with Phonegap Build.

While trying to include the `cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview` ([here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview)), Phonegap Build fails with a very generic error message ("Oh geez. Your build failed. Sorry, but a problem occurred on the build server").

Has anyone else experienced this? Or has anyone else been able to get Crosswalk to work with Phonegap Build?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official version in the PhoneGap Build curated plugins list will build for `arm`, though note that it is an older version. To use it:

```
<plugin name="org.crosswalk.engine" spec="1.3.0" source="pgb" />
```

for `x86`

```
<plugin name="org.crosswalk.engine.x86" spec="1.3.0" source="pgb" />
```

Alternatively [This plugin](https://github.com/MBuchalik/cordova-build-architecture) allows you to build either the x86 version or the arm version in PGB.

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview" source="npm" />
<plugin name="cordova-build-architecture" spec="https://github.com/MBuchalik/cordova-build-architecture.git#v1.0.1" source="git" />
<preference name="buildArchitecture" value="x86" />
```

Comment: I saw that official version in the PhoneGap Build plugins list but when I visit that list now, it tells me that list is deprecated and to use the NPM `cordova plugins` repository.

Also, with the latest update to PhoneGap Build, in the blog post I linked to it says to use the plugins hosted there and the only version of Crosswalk I see there is a newer one, which is why I thought there was a way to use that now.

Comment: does the alternative solution work for anyone? It still produces an .apk with both arm and x86 versions

Comment: were you able to make this work with phonegap build? :)

Comment: @bCliks thanks, which one did you use the pgb source or npm?

Comment: @Woppi npm version working fine. FYI: Access to pgb public plugins will be removed on November 15th, 2016.